# cakephp validation in model on two fields being unique

Tags: validation, cakephp, model

I am trying to amend my validation in my Model.

I need to check to see if (FIELD1 and FIELD2) are unique. For example

FIELD1 = "mattfacer" //username
FIELD2 = "1192" //chosen display ID

I need to check the database to see if the FIELD1 and FIELD2 have been used. If not, it should pass validation. If that display ID of 1192 and the username "mattfacer" has been used, return false for validation.

Is that possible? I was thinking of a custom validation function but not sure where I'd call it?

Thank you.

**[edit]**
The username and display ID are not unique in them selves.. it's the combination of the two which need to be unique. So there could be the following which is allowed

username = mattfacer
displayid = 6609

username = suziefacer
displayid = 6609

Those would be allowed.

**[/edit]**

Comment: Check out [Validate Uniqueness](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/07/maximum-power-for-your-validation-rules/).

Answer (score 0):

```
// you may be use this 
<?php
 public $validate = array('FIELD1' => array('beta' => array(
                                            'rule' => 'isUnique',
                                            'message' => 'This FIELD1 alreay exists!',
                                         )),
     'FIELD2'=> array('beta' => array(
                                            'rule' => 'isUnique',
                                            'message' => 'This FIELD2 alreay exists!',
                                         )
                        );
?>
```

Comment: that checks to see if each one is unique - but I need it to check the combination of FIELD1 and FIELD2. For example, there may be other customers with that display ID but their username would be different so it's OK. Checking the display ID is unique would fail.. but when including the username it would make it unique - does that make sense?